# Accessing SWT Libraries in Java modules in 32/64-Bit JVMs

Tags: eclipse, maven, swt, 32bit-64bit, java-module

Assuming you have a Java module that defines the following dependencies to SWT:

```
module com.test.mymodule {
 requires org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86;
}
```

If the module defined above is loaded within a 32-bit based JVM in Windows there are no issues, however within a 64-bit JVM this operation fails as the JVM tries to load native 32-bit libraries within the SWT JAR that then cause the JVM to crash. This will happen on the first line of code that references any SWT class (e.g. if you call Display.getShells). The JARs avaliable on [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86/4.3) do not define the Atomatic-Module-Name property in the manifest so trying to add the [64-bit version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/4.3) of the library leads to Maven being unable to parse the name of the file correctly.

Furtmore adding a static to the requires has exactly the same effect, as the JVM insists on loading the module specified in the module-info file. Is there any generic SWT module that can be used instead of system-specific modules so that the mymodule module in this sample would load regardless of the bitness/OS of the underlying JVM?

JDK Version:11.0.2, Windows 10 64-Bit

Comment: All SWT modules are specific to 32 or 64 bit and the platform they are designed for.

Comment: Of course do they not define any module name cause they are more than five years old. And yes they loading 32 bit dll cause this is component for win32 which mean 32 bit ...and that will not run on 64 bit jvm ... What do you mean by add the 64-bit version? It looks like there are no 64 bit version of that library on Central .. in the end I would say it's not possible with SWT cause it's depends on the JVM (32/64) ...As far as I know JDK 8 is last version which has 32/64 bit versions other s only have 64 bit versions...

Comment: Also checking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/swt/ you don't see 64 bit versions here...

Comment: @khmarbaise 64 bit SWT is available from the Eclipse download site.

Comment: Yes as download from Eclipse site but not a Maven repository which limits the usage (yes you can do things via P2 OSGi repositories but that's another story)...

Answer (score 1):

Both the 32-bit and 64 bit versions of SWT binaries are available in Maven Central. The binaries are published to Maven Central for every release.

Links to 64-bit binaries:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64

Please note that Eclipse has dropped support for 32-bit since Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) release.

Comment: Does an additional file need to be added to the POM file aside from one of the binares listed? If I add the 64-bit binary to the POM it fails to build because the 64-bit binary itself is missing a reference: "Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:jar:3.112.0 -> org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt:jar:3.105.2 -> org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.aarch64:jar:[3.105.2,3.105.2]: No versions available for org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.aarch64:jar:[3.105.2,3.105.2]"

Comment: @user1628056 In OSGi using both, the 32-bit and the 64-bit SWT binaries JARs in one application works in contrast to plain Java with or without JPMS. So you can use OSGi instead of plain Java or implement a combined 32/64-bit SWT binaries JAR yourself (see [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/)).